# How can I re-position jquery appended divs?

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

Im currently using soundclouds jquery player to add music to my site but I'd like to know how I can move the album covers from their current assigned position which is within the '$player' and move them into a div id called "#inner"?

currently the jquery looks like this

```
    $artworks = $('<ol class="sc-artwork-list"></ol>').appendTo($player),
    $list = $('<ol class="sc-trackslist"></ol>').appendTo($player);
```

full player script can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/Y7D2E/

Answer (score 0):

album covers are in var $artworks.
If you want to move them in to div id=#inner,
just change the line to `$artworks = $('<ol class="sc-artwork-list"></ol>').appendTo('#inner')`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work but for some reason when I append the sc-artwork-list to '#inner' the buttons that they once where become regular url links. Is there a solution to that? 

It works fine when its appended to $player :S